# How I can find my root directory at the server?

Tags: php, web

How I can find the root directory of my website at the server, and how do I refer a file that is not in the same directory in which the file goes in PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

The above line will give you the root directory of your website

You can directly define the path like a constant somewhere in your common includes file like

```
define('PATH_TO_PROJECT_ROOT', '/path/to/projectroot/');
```

and use the constant wherever  you want

Comment: How I can refer a file saved in other directory from the directory in which the file goes?

Comment: Consider abc.php file is stored in model folder and you want to call it in ui folder then include it<? include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/model/abc.php");?>